# Firefox on ARM debian

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, make, arm

I am trying to get firefox compiled on my arm [cubieboard](http://cubieboard.org) (Installed with Cubieez, a Debian wheezy armhf distribution), using apt-src, and the ubuntu quantal main source repository.

```
apt-src -bi install firefox
```

after building for 11 hours it says that No space left on device(4 GB USB-Stick). How much space should I have to get it compile? Is there any way to cross-compile deb-s (Other avaible systems: Ubuntu 12.04 x64, Windows 7 x64, Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (virtual), Windows XP x64 (virtual), Ubuntu 13.04 x64, my rooted ARM Android phone with gcc (but this might be slower than the original system) ). And also.. is it normal that it takes more than 11 hours?? I think it is not the apt-src wich is slow, because I already compiled m4 for autoconf (also from the Ubuntu quantal main repository), it took only 11 minutes, not 11 hours.
So how could I compile firefox for the device? (will not buy SATA winchester only to build it)
Or, is there somewhere a precompiled version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't it come with a precompiled or `apt-get`-able ice weasel? Their [website](http://cubieboard.org/2013/12/21/a-debian-image-for-cubieboard2-cubieez/) says so, at least.

Firefox is a long, involved build for a desktop, so doing on a pin of a system is probably not the best bet. A lot of distros for that hardware seem to already have official firefox binaries for `apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: 'apt-get install firefox' installs firefox 16, but the latest version is **26**. And yes there is iceweasel, but that is old too, and i don't like it at all.

Comment: Unless your Cubie somehow meets [these requirements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build) I don't think you'll be building it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, i had memory problems, but not critical. So this is why it was so slow. But how about cross-compiling?

Comment: You can follow [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Cross-Compiling_Mozilla), though it's hardly copy and paste. If you want something really up to date for some reason, that should work.